# Service layer and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to Rails. I'm using Service layer to keep my controllers thin. All my service layer files are located in `app/services/domain`, `app/services/application`, `app/services/infrastructure`. For example here is the my company service:

```
class CompanyService

  def self.create(params)
    company = Company.new(params)
    rst = true
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      begin
        company.save!
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        rst = false
      rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
        rst = nil
      end
    end
    return company, rst
  end

  def self.update(params)
    company = get_company(params[:id])
    rst = true
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      begin
        company.old_category_ids = company.category_ids
        company.assign_attributes(params[:company])

        decrease_category_ids = company.old_category_ids-company.category_ids
        decrease_counters(decrease_category_ids)

        increase_category_ids = company.category_ids-company.old_category_ids
        increase_counters(increase_category_ids)

        company.save!
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        rst = false
      rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
        rst = nil
      end
    end
    return company, rst
  end # end update
```

And here is the company controller:

```
    def create
      @company, rst = CompanyService.create(params[:company])
      if rst == true
        redirect_to(admin_companies_url, notice: "Company was successfully created.")
      elsif rst == false
        render active_admin_template('new.html.erb')
      else
        redirect_to admin_companies_url, notice: "Something went wrong. Please try again."
      end
    end

    def update
      @company, rst = CompanyService.update(params)
      if rst
        redirect_to admin_company_url(company), notice: "Company was successfully updated."
      elsif rst == false
        render active_admin_template('edit.html.erb')
      elsif rst == nil
        redirect_to admin_companies_url, notice: "Something went wrong. Please try again."
      end
    end

    def destroy
      CompanyService.destroy(params[:id])
      redirect_to admin_companies_url
    end
```

So I have two questions:

1. I know my controller code is not good. How to improve it?
2. My services are not automatically loaded in production and development environment. Why?

Sorry for poor English. Thank you for every advice and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you dont want to use the models and abstracting model interactions through services?

to load your services automatically you should include services path in autoload config.autoload_paths inside your config/application.rb

You also have a double check on bad record (invlid record or invalid statement), your user experience is going to be the same regardless of why the record was not saved so there is no reason to have nested ifs. Your controller should just know if the action was successful or not

Comment: I'm using service layer in API. So I need a move my business logic to service layer.

Comment: Are you building an api or are you consuming 3rd party api? if you are bulding an api layer you would be better off moving it into its own namespaces, if you are consuming it should belong in a model

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. I'm building an API.